# Dropdown list in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, html-select

In my web application Iam adding a **Dropdownlist ("ddlState")** to my **GridviewData("gviewdata" is binded with SQLDatasource)**, through **ITEMTEMPLATE**. It works fine, but the drodown is added as first cell. **Is it possible to add it as last value**...????

Page.aspx:

---

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gviewPermissionHistory" runat="server" 
             Width="85%" onrowdatabound="gviewPermissionHistory_RowDataBound">
             <Columns>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" >
                       <asp:ListItem Text="Approved" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem Text="Declined" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                  </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
             </Columns>
    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#3D5E8B" ForeColor="White" />

</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can you add your code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define all your values in this gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gviewPermissionHistory" runat="server" 
             Width="85%" onrowdatabound="gviewPermissionHistory_RowDataBound">
             <Columns>
               <asp:BoundField DataField="Field1" />
               <asp:BoundField DataField="Field2" />
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" >
                       <asp:ListItem Text="Approved" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem Text="Declined" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                  </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
             </Columns>
    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#3D5E8B" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are generating Columns Automatically, then the defined column will be placed first. Theres a lot of ways to archieve this, there's some:

1) You could specify every column from the DataSources in the correct order, and then put the  `ddlStatus` in the last position.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gviewPermissionHistory" runat="server" 
         Width="85%" onrowdatabound="gviewPermissionHistory_RowDataBound">
         <Columns>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="MyFieldHere1" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="MyFieldHere2" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="MyFieldHere3" />
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State">
              <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" >
                   <asp:ListItem Text="Approved" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                   <asp:ListItem Text="Declined" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
              </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
         </Columns>
<RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#3D5E8B" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
```

2) You could change the order in the code behind, for exemple:

```
var columnToMove = myGridView.Columns[1];
myGridView.Columns.RemoveAt(1);
myGridView.Columns.Insert(0, columnToMove);
```